# br line-height in safari and chrome leaving gap

Tags: css, html, safari, google-chrome

In my HTML I have a `<div>`, and inside the `<div>` I need different vertical spacing between lines of text.  I'm achieving this by using `<br />` elements with a CSS class that corresponds to the amount of spacing I want.

For instance, for a 5px gap, I use a `<br>` with the `height5` class:

```html
<br /><br class="height5" />
```

Similarly, `height2` and `height10` and whatever exist for the same purpose.

The CSS classes are defined like so:

```css
br.height2 {line-height:2px;}
br.height5 {line-height:5px;}
```

This is working in IE6+, FF2+, and Opera but for some reason there are huge gaps in Safari and Chrome (as if those two browsers are ignoring it and just applying regular breaks).  I tried testing with larger line-heights like 20px or 30px and Safari and Chrome recognize those.  They seem to be ignoring anything under 5-10 pixels.

Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This worked on Chrome (the `content` attribute did the trick):

```css
br {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Styling the br was necessary because a rich-text editor I use would leave large gaps between texts.

Answer (score 3):

Those browsers might be reading your white space (carriage return, etc) and propping it open with a &nbsp;sort of value. I suggest using multiple div tags and style the divs with margin-bottom attributes of the space you want.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 2px">content</div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px">content</div>
<div>content</div>
```

Comment: yes, <br /> is almost like goto :) Some smart browsers can ignore font-sizes smaller than 9px to prevent users' eyes damage. And spaces between elements must be discribed in CSS as spaces, not as text line-brakes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but my answer here is cross-browser without turning br into a block

```
/* line height can be set to whatever you want*/
br {line-height: 0.1; content: " "}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
br { line-height: 1em; }
```

or:

```
br { margin-top: 2em; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for both firefox and chrome. Got the idea from @SamuelC and @anushr.

```
br{ 
    display: block;
    line-height: 0.1; 
    content: " ";
}
```