# In HTML do you insert a small space in between lines

Tags: html, css, spacing

When I use `<p>` I get to large of a space but when I use `<br\>` I don't get large enough of a space.

[image]

I want a large space between "Glucose Levels" and "I have recently been diagnosed..."

Comment: Without your corresponding mark-up this doesn't seem to qualify as a 'question.' What you want can be achieved via fairly simple CSS.

Comment: One might take this as a hint to use `p` rather than `br`.

Comment: looks like you should be using a header followed by a paragraph for the correct semantics. Use CSS to style the margins.

Comment: Incidentally, shouldn't the `<br\>` be `<br />`? Or is this something new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using proper mark-up, ideally semantic mark-up, for your content aids you greatly in styling that content:

```
<h1>What vitamins amd supplements help control glucose levels?</h1>
<p>I am a recently diagnosed type-II diabetic. Lately, my glucose levels have been very high.</p>
```

With the css:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0; /* removes any default margin placed on the h1 element */
}
h1 + p { /* selects only those p elements immediately following a h1 */
    margin: 1em 0 0 0; /* short hand for margin-top margin-right margin-bottom margin-left */
}
```

Results in this [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jWqaL/1/).

Answer (score 2):

It's been answered here:
[How to change the height of a <br>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-height-of-a-br)

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the paragraph (P) and assign a css class to it. With that css class you can set the top and or bottom margins.

abc

simple as 1, 2, 3

.intro
{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try using Heading `<h1>, <h2>, <h3>` elements instead of Paragraph elements.

Also, use Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) for an extreme level of control over your presentation.  In this case you could use the margin-bottom attribute to control your spacing.  Check w3schools for good CSS tutorials or just use Google.

Answer (score 0):

Try line-height in your css.

or alternative
try to set a margin-top, margin-bottom on your br element.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the first text ("What...levels?") in a div, give it an id and than change the css property "margin-bottom:Xpx;" where X is the height of the space between two textes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple different options...

1. Adjust the margin and/or padding for the class on on your <p> elements
2. Insert a div with width="100%" and height equal to the space you want between the elements

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do what was asked, insert a small space between two lines, this is working for me.