# Does BR tag posseses height?

Tags: html

I know that BR is used to create line-breaks. I'm just wondering if it also creates space between lines? Please consider these example:

```
<p>
Hello <br/> Stackoverflow <br/><br/><br/> !
</p>
```

The output looks like:

```
Hello
Stackoverflow


!
```

By putting more and more BR I found distance between lines increase. Is it because of `<br>`? But when I try to control `<br>` height in CSS, it doesn't follow, it seems like it has no height at all, just a line-break. If `<br>` is not the cause of the space between line, then which is which and how to control it in CSS? Also, I usually use `<br>` to create large distance between lines, I do that to replace `\n\r` or the like when the data is from the database, is that okay?

Comment: One solution is here for `<br>` height- http://stackoverflow.com/a/20488415/2165415
==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the space that we see when we put multiple BR is not actually caused by BR but the P element's line height.

Consider the following markup:

```
<p>
Hello <br/> Stackoverflow <br/><br/><br/> !
</p>
```

Output

```
1. Hello
2. Stackoverflow 
3. 
4.    
5.    !
```

Line 3 and 4 here are just empty lines. Despite being empty, they still posses line height.

Answer (score 6):

The `<br />` tag is for line breaks. You can use the CSS line-height property to control distance between lines, if you want to look at it that way.

Answer (score 5):

for large distances between lines, is better to use `<p>` tags for every line, in which you can control the height.

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/f6ju2/

Comment: `p` is a good option, please see my edit about newline. How am I going to use `p` when the text is from a database?

Answer (score 2):

*The BR element forcibly breaks (ends) the current line of text*...

More info [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.2.1). and yes, adding more will increase the distance but I don't believe you can do much for styling it except applying `clear`.

Answer (score 2):

The number of <br /> used does only create line breaks.  If you are desiring to create large space between specific sections on the page I would use CSS margin attribute to distance one top section from the next.  For example:

```
<div id="topSection" class="margin-bottom: 100px;">Hello Stackflow</div>
<div id="bottomSection">Content lower on the screen without unnecessary breaks.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by putting more `BR` tags new line breaks will be created. It is not preferred to use `BR` tags to create large distances between lines, rather use CSS `margin` and `padding` to introduce spaces.

Comment: I also thinking of using margin and padding. Please see my edit about newline from the database.

Comment: In that case, use a regular expression to replace `BR` with `P`. See working [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ju2/2/).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using `<br />` to get the spacing you like in between lines, you can use the CSS `line-height` property

Comment: So you mean those spaces are not from `BR` but from default `line-height`?

Comment: The spaces between `Stackoverflow` and `!` are due to the `<br />` tags you have added. When using the `line-height` CSS property, you can alter the spacing between lines (whether they are forcibly broken or not)

Answer (score 0):

I found that `line-height` works well in CSS. :)

```css
p {
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:280%;
}
```

```html
<p>
Hello
<br>
World!
</p>
```