# 1px line gap between two asp elements?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I want to be able to control the gap between two asp elements.

The gap got from  is too much and id like to reduce it to half of that. I tried using the following modified br tah to no avail.

Please advise.

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server"  ImageUrl="/_Layouts/Bullet.png" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4"  runat="server" CssClass="PreviousPollLinkButtonStyle"  Onclick="renderingCurrentPoll">Current Poll</asp:LinkButton>
 **<br style="line-height:2px;"/>**
 <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/_Layouts/Bullet.png" />&nbsp<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="PreviousPollLinkButtonStyle" Onclick="renderingPreviousPollResults">Previous Poll Results</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your Image and LinkButton in a DIV and use a bottom-margin:

```
<div style="bottom-margin:1px;padding:0;">
 <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server"  ImageUrl="/_Layouts/Bullet.png" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4"  runat="server" CssClass="PreviousPollLinkButtonStyle"  Onclick="renderingCurrentPoll">Current Poll</asp:LinkButton> 
</div>

 <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/_Layouts/Bullet.png" />&nbsp<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="PreviousPollLinkButtonStyle" Onclick="renderingPreviousPollResults">Previous Poll Results</asp:LinkButton>
```

You may have to change the PreviousPollLinkButtonStyle CSS class.

Comment: Thanks Dave! That did the trick! But just curiiosity's sake, is there a way to modify the <br> tag to acheive this?

Comment: @user1266515 - Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/1409649/139917 for modifying the <br/> tag through CSS. As the correct answer states, "It's a very, very dirty solution (and probably not even cross-browser compatible), but it's something at least."