# On usage of <br> tag line-height does not work. Why?

Tags: css

```
<div style="line-height:25px;">
First line of the content<br />
Second line of the content<br />
Third line of the content<br />
</div>
```

On usage of break tag in a `<div>`, the line-height property is not working with any of the attributes:

```
line-height:20px;
line-height:100%;
line-height:1.5;
```

Now the three lines are displayed with default line height and not with the specified `line-height` 25px. But if the `<div>` contains no break tag between the lines, the line height works. How to override this?

Comment: How do you want to apply a line height to a <br />? Think about what a br is. it has no content and only makes a carrier return. line height would have no effect on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `<br />` is an inline element, you need to apply `line-height` to a block element such as `<p>`.

```
<p style="line-height: 20px;">
This is some text<br />with a break tag.
</p>
```

You want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-height-of-a-br) question regarding turning `<br />` into a block element.