# Spacing issues with <br>

Tags: asp.net, html, css

```
<div class="w-box-header" style="text-align: right;">
<div class="footer-text">
My Support Representative
</div>
<div>
<asp:Label ID="mcr_Name" runat="server" Text="Test Joe" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="mcr_email" runat="server" Text="mailto@gmail.com" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="mcr_phone" runat="server" Text="P: (800) 555-5555 ext. 143" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="mcr_fax" runat="server" Text="F: (555) 555-5555" />
</div>
</div>
```

The `<br>` is causing a lot of space to be put above/below the labels.  Is there any way to override this spacing and have them be right under each other?

It looks like this:

Test Joe

mailto@gmail.com

P: (800) 555-5555 ext. 143

F: (555) 555-5555

How to force it like this:

Test Joe
mailto@gmail.com
P: (800) 555-5555 ext. 143
F: (555) 555-5555

Comment: pls put css of this html coding

Comment: [How to change height of a break tag][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-height-of-a-br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using divs, and remove BR's

```
  <div class="w-box-header" style="text-align: right;">
        <div class="footer-text">
            My Engagex Support Representative
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="mcr_Name" runat="server" Text="Test Joe" />
           </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="mcr_email" runat="server" Text="mailto@gmail.com" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="mcr_phone" runat="server" Text="P: (800) 555-5555 ext. 143" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="mcr_fax" runat="server" Text="F: (555) 555-5555" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This seemed to be the simplest and did the trick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is probably a misuse of `<label>`. You aren't labeling anything, just displaying text.

> The label element represents a caption for a form control (w3)

Secondly, `<br>` should be used where the division of lines is significant, not for style purposes (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/br)).

For ASP.Net, I would use a simpler structure:

```
<div><asp:Literal runat="server" text="Foo" /></div>
<div><asp:Literal runat="server" text="Bar" /></div>
<div><asp:Literal runat="server" text="Baz" /></div>
```

Also see: [Marking up contacts using semantic HTML5 & microformats](http://rachaelmoore.name/posts/design/html/html5-microdata-contact-info/) for more advanced techniques.

Comment: This is the design phase, next phase I will be updating the label with information obtained from a login.  Could still use a literal for that I suppose.

Comment: A label should usually be paired with a form element. If you just need to display text (even if it's form-related) a label isn't necessary (although nothing bad will happen).

Comment: As a note, an `asp:label` will increase the size of your viewstate.

Comment: I have switched them to literals.  Getting better and better each day. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add padding to your labels via CSS, change their display to block, and remove the br tags entirely

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
<div class="w-box-header" style="text-align: right;">
<div class="footer-text">
My Engagex Support Representative
</div>
<div>
<asp:Label ID="mcr_Name" runat="server" Text="Test Joe"  style="display:inline-block;"/><br />
<asp:Label ID="mcr_email" runat="server" Text="mailto@gmail.com" style="display:inline-block;"/><br />
<asp:Label ID="mcr_phone" runat="server" Text="P: (800) 555-5555 ext. 143" style="display:inline-block;"/><br />
<asp:Label ID="mcr_fax" runat="server" Text="F: (555) 555-5555" style="display:inline-block;"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you put div, then it will still generate some padding because, the default display property for div is 'block'.

Comment: The use of inline-block is exactly like '\n' in c#. will move to next line without padding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this problem is not to hard to fix. You need to write a CSS style for the 
 tag to change its default settings (which are determined by a users web browser). The are two properties that can effect the distance between the 
 tags. The first is called the margin, this has a default value within web browsers.

Here is some code for adjusting the margin:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">
br {
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

</style>
```

Alternatively, you might need to change the padding

```
...
<style type="text/css">
br {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
</style>
```

If neither of these work after setting their values to "0px" and spacing still remains, then the issue is not with the 
 tags. It could be either the padding or margin of other tag elements like `<img /> , <p>` or whatever else is adjacent to your 
 tags.

Although this answer was not chosen as a solution to this question, here is a diagram of the properties used by html and CSS for stylizing layouts for the web:
[image]

In most cases of programming, there are many ways to arrive at the same answer. Just make sure that you are consistent in how you solve similar problems across the site.

Comment: Using the <div> tag is more appropriate for structuring layout like this as changing the style for the <br> tags will change how all the br tags appear on entire page, not just the ones used in your cited code. There is a balance between creating the right ammount of divs and creating too many. Mate's answer is a little div heavy, you can still use the <br> tags, but also give the wrapping div an id or class. This would enable you to be able to write a compound style for the given <br> tags. Check out www.w3schools.com to see references on CSS styles.

Comment: Thank you for the extra work, I really as just looking for the quick and dirty for this solution.  I know it is a bit div heavy, but it got me past a hurdle and then a task which allowed me to move onto my next task in this project with a deadline. =(

Comment: @James No worries, thanks for the support. I just want to help out those who may search this topic and arrive at your question. I use stack overflow to find a lot of answers I can't find in other references.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to remove the `<br />` tags and instead use CSS to style those lines the way you wish. If you want to display each piece of information on individual lines you can specify that they should be displayed as "blocks" in CSS.

```
<div> 
    <asp:Label ID="mcr_Name" runat="server" Text="Test Joe" style="display:block;" />
    <asp:Label ID="mcr_email" runat="server" Text="mailto@gmail.com" style="display:block;" />
    <asp:Label ID="mcr_phone" runat="server" Text="P: (800) 555-5555 ext. 143" style="display:block;" />
    <asp:Label ID="mcr_fax" runat="server" Text="F: (555) 555-5555" style="display:block;" />
</div>
```

To reduce verbosity and duplication of that CSS code, you can move the style definition to the `<head>` element in your markup like so:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .block {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <asp:Label ID="mcr_Name" runat="server" Text="Test Joe" class="block" />
        <asp:Label ID="mcr_email" runat="server" Text="mailto@gmail.com" class="block" />
        <asp:Label ID="mcr_phone" runat="server" Text="P: (800) 555-5555 ext. 143" class="block" />
        <asp:Label ID="mcr_fax" runat="server" Text="F: (555) 555-5555" class="block" />
    </div>
</body>
```

I personally avoid using the `<br />` tag as much as I can. I've found it to be much better to use HTML markup (like `<div>`, `<br />` etc.) to provide only the **structure** of the document and not the style.

When dealing with the **style** of your web page (spacing, fonts, colours etc.), I've had much better success sticking to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your CSS

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```