# Best way to give a newline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that looks like this:

```
    <form class="navbar-form text-center">
        <input type="text" class="span2">
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" class="span2">
        <p></p>
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">I'm Done</button>
    </form>
```

Right now I'm using the `<p></p>` block, but that seems far from elegant to me.

I'd like to know if there was a better way because I searched a bit and couldn't find one.
Thanks!

EDIT: I'd like to avoid additional HTML if possible like br and p tags.

Comment: .span { margin-bottom: 1em; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a pure CSS solution, you could use:

```
input.span2 {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple answer: use a [**br**eaking space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/br).

For example:

```
a
<br>
b
```

Will render like this:

```
a
b
```

If you want a space between your elements, just add another `<br>`, like so:

```
a
<br>
<br>
b
```

Which will render like this:

```
a

b
```

Comment: You can also make new lines with `\n` too

Comment: Good idea, but the space is either too little or too much with a single or double br. I know I'm really picky...

Comment: @Killrawr `\n` is different to `<br>`. `\n` renders a new-line only in the source code. `<br>` renders a new-line to the screen.

Comment: @Xaranke Take a look at the accepted answer here: [How to change height of a <br>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1409649)

Answer (score 1):

See http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <input type="text" >
</div>
```

Comment: This would be excellent for larger forms, but I think that I'll be working with a dozen elements at max so it feels like overkill. Thanks for the link and I will keep this in mind.

Comment: this is the recommended way of breaking up bootstrap forms! :)  you're generally not supposed to use any kind of 'fudge' HTML code with bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking that you shouldn't add additional HTML purely for presentation that adds no semantic value.  CSS Is on your side.

```
.span2 {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AGp2g/