# Align text with new line in the middle of icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

There is an icon with a text in front of it. I can align the text in the middle of icon by using `style="vertical-align: middle;"`

So below works fine:

```
<i class="fa fa-arrows-alt fa-5x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> a Big Arrow.
```

The problem is when we add a `<br>` the alignment is not work any more ( As the icon is simple character)

```
<i class="fa fa-arrows-alt fa-5x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> a Big Arrow </br> I mean very Big!
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/tQYTB/1/

Can you tell me what is the best solution for it!

Comment: you can absolutely style a break. for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br

Comment: ^^ @Carnotaurus: You can style a break!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tQYTB/3/

Basically, wrap the label text in a span

#### HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-arrows-alt fa-5x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
<span class="label">a Big Arrow. <br/> I mean real Big</span>
```

#### CSS

```
.label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use span tag whenever you want to change some portion of the content.......

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

[image]