# How to set height on multiple br tags with different height?

Tags: html, css

I'm using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br) the accepted one to get custom `<br />` height:

```
br {display: block;margin: 0.5em 0;content: "";}
```

But this technique produce the same result for single `<br />` or double `<br /><br />` or tripple `<br /><br /><br />`.

So, how can I use, so that the height of br would be different as per the times br inserted?

Comment: Why are you using <br />?

Comment: @bjb568 can you tell me the better way?

Comment: Use a container (div, section, p, whatever is semantically correct) with a margin-top.

Comment: I think `<br />` would be better than blank `<div class="myclass"></div>`

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: If you have to have an empty element just to add vertical space, then an empty div is better than a br (which is supposed to be used only to add a line break inside text.) The best solution would be to not have a separate element at all but add the space to the previous or following element instead.

Answer (score 1):

There might be [margin-collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), so try setting padding instead of margin:

```
br {display: block;padding: 0.5em 0;content: "";}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
br{
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

br ~ br{
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

etc..

http://jsfiddle.net/7uvFe/

and i don't even know why i keep getting down votes.

Comment: @bjb568 `<br />` `<br /><br />` etc.. as per op stated

Comment: Yes, but it fails when there are multiple text-separated <br />s in on container.