# Can I have a different <p> break size to a <br> size?

Tags: html

```
<p> Cheese </p>
<p> Apples </p>

<p> Potatoes <br>
Carrots </p>
```

I'd like the line break between 'Cheese' and 'Apples' to be a different size between the line break between 'Potatoes' and 'Carrots' due to the lines breaking in different ways.

Would this be possible.

Sorry, complete noob, just trying to learn HTML.

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web

Comment: Have a look at this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br

Comment: @mb21 Tried that, wasn't very helpful. I've learnt more starting from scratch and learning from my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of a line within a paragraph is determined by the CSS `line-height` property.

The space between paragraphs is determined by the CSS `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties.

Answer (score 0):

What the others say is true; both approaches work. 
You can also use an inline style if you really only want to control *one* paragraph -- you can do:

```
style="margin:10px;"
```

or whatever distance you need, as an attribute in your

tag.
This kind of CSS inline style should be used sparingly, though.