# Spacing blocks with line break

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

I would like to know the following, the blogger is very clueless, because it removes the paragraphs `<p>`, and add line breaks. '`<br>`'

The problem that line breaks I can not spacing, the most I do is adiconar a `line-height: 30px;`

There is something in the css to make the addition of blocks as the paragraph because the blogger I only have line break:

```
<p> Block 1 </ p>
<p> Block 2 </ p>
<p> Block 3 </ p>
```

Blogger:

```
Text 1 </ br>
text 2 </ br>
text 3 </ br>
```

I thought about using JS, convert 
 in

. Something like:

```
$ ('.post').append ('<p>').prepend ('</p>')..;
$ ('.post br').replaceWith ('</p><p>');
```

Would I can solve this problem without using JS, JS because I would have to remove tags like `<code>, <pre>` etc ...

Comment: this should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br

Comment: I was using chrome and had tried margin, and chrome does not work, worked with line-height in <BR> ATT ...