# What is the default height of <br> elements?

Tags: css, padding

I'm working with a web page which currently uses `<br>` tags for spacing and page layout, and I want to remove all these tags and replace them with an equivalent in CSS to make the page more accessible to screen readers.

As part of this process, I need to replace the break tags that are currently used for spacing with CSS-based padding.

Could someone tell me what the default line break height is so that I can set my padding to equal that height and save a lot of time?

Comment: It should be the same as the default line-height of your document...i think.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. <br> is a line break. It doesn't have a height, it just breaks the line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br

Comment: Doesn't replacing mean, removing the element?  As in getting rid of the break tag?  I also don't follow your question.

Comment: To clarify, you mean to say you're working with a web page which incorrectly uses `<br/>` tags for formatting, and you need to replace those tags with an equivalent in CSS, right? I'm going to edit to clear things up a bit, feel free to revert if my edit changes the intent of your question.

Comment: I think it is `1.2` or `120%`. That's all I know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `<br>` element represents a line break. The height of a line break is determined by the current line height of the portion of the document the break element is in.

The default line height depends on a number of factors, including the browser you're using and the current font family. You can find the exact computed line height for any given element in Chrome by inspecting the element, switching to the computed style tab, and filtering for the `line-height` property. In most browsers, you should be able to approximate this height with a length value of around `1.2em`. For more on `em` units, see the section on [relative length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Relative_length_units) from MDN.

Comment: It's easy to read your answer as if you're stating `<br>` equals the `line-height` value, which is not the case. The height of a `<br>` element is derived from the line height using a formula. To test this, try resetting all styles and setting a line height close to the default rem value, e.g., `body * {all: unset; line-height: 1rem;}`. Any `<br>` elements should have no height. As the line height increases, `<br>` should begin to receive height, e.g., `body * {all: unset; line-height: 2rem;}`.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund I can reproduce your example in Chrome, but not in Firefox. In Firefox it says the br height is 16 in that first example, not 0. https://jsfiddle.net/91qfgoyt/ Though I think its pretty clear from the question that the OP isn't specifically talking about the height property of the br elements anyway, just the apparent "height" of the line breaks themselves.

Comment: The core of the question is how to determine the height of a <br> element. Since it doesn't have an intrinsic height, figuring out its actual height is a challenge. The nearest line-height would make sense intuitively, but that's not how browsers determine it. You're right that Firefox reports 16px, but that doesn't match the actual height on the screen. To me, it looks more like 3 px. Chrome and Safari at least don't report an incorrect height, but they also don't provide the actual height.