# Different <br> height between Firefox and other browsers

Tags: html, css

I made a site about Star Wars Canon timeline (with movies,tv shows, books and comics) and I have a slight problem.

Chrome/Opera/Vivaldi have different < br> tag heights compared to Firefox and it crushes my OCD.

Is there any way to make the site look the same way on Firefox as it does on Chrome/Opera/Vivaldi?

I am sorry if I am not made understood, here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se4zH.png

Comment: Use html5 break: `<br />`

Comment: Just force it to have the same size via CSS. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br

Comment: ***Do not use `<br>` to increase the gap between lines of text;** use the CSS margin property or the `<p>` element.* Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: @gmo Also what he says, I totally agree.

Answer (score 2):

<sup><sub>Yes, I have OCD as well and am verily frustrated by such imperfections.</sub></sup>

You may style your `<br>` with CSS:

```
br {
  line-height: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

or by in-line styling, as provided by @Raj Kumar in a previous answer:

```
<br style="line-height: 2rem; height: 2rem;" />
```

Try a snippet here:

```html
<br style="line-height: 10px; height: 10px;">
<!-- I used 10px to emphasise the height. You can use !important, too, if your code is not obedient. See? It works.-->
```

If this does not work, what I'd advise you to do would be to completely omit the `<br>` tags and add either **`margin`**, `padding`, or invisible borders (`border: 2px groove transparent;`) to the elements you're seperating. Another not-so-neat way is to add transparent a `div` (`div.class {background: transparent; width: 100%; height: 2px;}`).

<sup>You might want to try to add <kbd>/</kbd> in your `<br />` tag (just in case) (although most modern browsers already support `<br>`). Make sure you don't have any additional spaces in your code, too (just for neatness). Also try to import [`normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [`vanilla.css`](http://noscope.com/vanilla-css/) and check if it fixes the problem.</sup>

<sup><sub>Thanks for letting me know about Vivaldi. Looks like a nice browser!</sub></sup>

Comment: Tried your version with 
`br {
  line-height: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}`
but it makes the br a lot bigger.

Comment: That's just an example. You may change the value to the heights you want (e.g. `2px`, `0.33rem`, `3mm`, `0.1cm`, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, I understood that that was an example, what I didn't understand was the value, never used "rem" before.

Comment: Oh! CSS3 introduced a few new units, including the rem unit, which stands for 'root em'. The em unit is relative to the font-size of the parent, which causes the compounding issue...

Comment: There is no closing slash in HTML for `<br>`. While allowed, it means nothing, does nothing and browsers are instructed by the specification to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try normalize css below is link http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

It will solve other problems of cross browser problems

Answer (score 0):

add styles for br It should work perfect check this

```
<br style="line-height:?px; height:?px" />
```

Comment: doesn't change anything, it acts exactly the same

Comment: give some px for line-height and height.

Comment: can i get the demo link of the page

Answer (score 0):

you may try with the

- reset.css
- normalize.css
- vanilla.css

that allows to reset all or particular element as per your requirement.