# HTML not reading %0A

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

I have this code:

```
elf='%0A';
document.getElementById('writebox').innerHTML=("hello there"+elf+"friend");
```

When the function that this is inside is called, the text that appears in the div is not a line break, but rather just "%0a". This confuses me, because inside another different function, elf works fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: Inside ordinary HTML the linefeed is ignored by the browser - use <br> instead. Why it may work in another area is that the html element could be  either a textarea or a pre tag

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Different encoding. `%0A` is URL-encoding of a newline, which you would use in (obviously) URLs. `&#x0a;` would be the HTML-encoding of the same character that you would use in HTML, but it doesn't work, for a variety of reasons. To break a line in HTML, you can use `<br>` tag.

**EDIT**:

> the problem wit a `<br />` tag is that all i want is simply a new line. `<br />` creates WAY too much white space

No, it doesn't:

```html
foo<br>
bar
```

Comment: the problem wit a <br /> tag is that all i want is simply a new line. <br /> creates WAY too much white space.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon In that case, [style the `<br />`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br) tag with CSS to make it appear like you'd like it to