# How to divide a document in sections without showing the <h*> tags when using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: html, css, pdf, webkit, wkhtmltopdf

I'm implementing a catalog using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

In order to generate the table of contents I must place the  tags in the document, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt):

> The table of content is generated based on the H tags in the input
>   documents. First a XML document is generated, then it is converted to
>   HTML using XSLT.

For product design reasons I need to make it so that such strings are neither displayed nor they take space in the final PDF.

I tried to use absolute positioning and using the "transparent" color to hide the text, however sometimes this doesn't work well, since wkhtmltopdf excludes them from the toc. I guess that the webkit engine optimizes them out.

Is it possible to somehow "tag" the content instead of including the actual HTML tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after quite a few attempts and testing I might have found a solution for this problem.

Mark your sections with the H tags. For example:

```html
<h1 class="section-marker">Section title</h1>
[... content]
<h2 class="section-marker">Sub-Section title</h2>
[... content]
<h3 class="section-marker">Sub-Sub-Section title</h3>
[... content]
```

To make sure that such tags are not visible and don't occupy any space (and wkhtmltopdf still catches them) you can use these CSS rules:

```css
.section-marker {
    width: 2px !important;
    height: 2px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    font-size: 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

---

**UPDATE: below my original answer, which was suboptimal. After some tests I adapted @lorenzo-s css solution to a more "universal" version that should always work (@lorenzo-s's solution was not working in my case) and doesn't require any "section-separator".**

To make sure that such tags are not visible and don't occupy any space (and wkhtmltopdf still catches them) you can use these CSS rules:

```
.section-marker {
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent;
    float: left;
  }
```

I noticed one small problem though. If 2 H tags are adjacent, wkhtmltopdf fails to recognize them as separate markers (perhaps because of the float property, I'm not sure).

Something like this will not work properly:

```html
<h1 class="section-marker">Section title</h1>
<h2 class="section-marker">Sub-Section title</h2>
```

You need to change it to this:

```html
<h1 class="section-marker">Section title</h1>
<br class="section-separator">
<h2 class="section-marker">Sub-Section title</h2>
```

with these rules (which I derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409742/431668) and some trial/error attempts):

```
br.section-separator {
  content:' ';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2px;
  line-height:2px;
}
```

Comment: If you use my styles instead of floating elements, do you still need the extra `section-separator` element for adjacent headings?

Comment: @lorenzo-s yes, I tried replacing the content of `section-marker` with your styles and the TOC was not correctly generated. Apparently `section-separator` seems to be needed in these special cases. If I use your code *and* the separator then the TOC is generated correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I actually use hidden `<h*>` with success. But the absolute positing didn't worked for me too. Here's my styles for hidden outline headings:

```
width: 1px !important;
height: 1px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 -1px -1px 0 !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
opacity: 0 !important;
```

The trick is letting the headings have actual size (1x1 px), hiding them with opacity and avoid they take 1px space with the negative margins.

> Is it possible to somehow "tag" the content instead of including the actual HTML tags?

I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I tested your solution and it works perfectly in hiding the H tags. However I had to add in this case as well the "section-separator" tags to make sure that the TOC was correctly generated.