# Make <br> line breaks bigger than normal line spaces

Tags: html, css

I have a small HTML website where it displays information (specifically, train stations) in an HTML table. On one row it has a fixed length, meaning that sentences longer than the width of the table overflow on to the next line. This is fine, but I need it so that it is obvious when the gap in-between lines is because of a long phrase or because it is the next in a list. See the example below:

[image]

There are two stops for this train, Reading (which fits on one line) and London Paddington (which overflows onto a second line). I need it so that the gap between 'Reading' and 'London' is larger than the gap between 'London' and 'Paddington'. The HTML for it looks like this:

```
<p>Calling at:<br>Reading<br>London Paddington</p>
```

I have tried to make this clear but if you don't understand please just say! Thank you.

Also, I have tried the solution at stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649 and it did not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the height of a <br>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br)

Comment: Why are you using a `br` here? Since `Reading` and `London Paddington` are different entities, you should wrap each in a block element such as a `div` or `li`

Comment: I have my reasons - to be precise, I need to change the stops later on using JS and this is how I want to do it.

Comment: It would be more semantic to use an `<ol>`. Please don't compromise usability and accessibility for ease of coding!

Comment: line-height, reset on font-size for br ... did you try anithing yet ?

Comment: I tried settings margins, line height and padding but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look at  `font-size` reset to `<br/>` only:

example, second paragraph shows line breaks increased.

```css
/* increase line-height on break line tags */

p+p br {
  font-size: 1.5em;/* tune your own value use calc(1em + 10px) or vmin,vmax, ... whatever */
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid;
  font-size: 1em;
}

p+p {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<p>Calling at:<br>Reading<br>London Paddington</p>
<p>Calling at:<br>Reading<br>London Paddington</p>
```

[image: result expected]
https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/brXQgQ

Comment: In the code snippet preview I can't see any difference between the black and green. Am I missing something?

Comment: @penguin_k what browser do you use (tested with IE11, chrome & ff and even the old and latest safari for windows .. that one is useless to test but stillremains on my pc). thanks for your feedback :)  I added a pic of the expected resut from FF