# Choosing the space height - HTML

Tags: html

Is it possible to like adjust the height of `<br>`or use a different command for it? Right now when you use `<br>` it's like pressing enter once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the height of a <br>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br)

Comment: If you are posting a question on stack first go to the search bar and check that is the question asked by someone before. You have the clearest solution possible for your question.  check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS

```
br {
   display: block;
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

or
     margin-top: 10px;

from

[How to change the height of a <br>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `line-height:` on the actual text. This should make the space between the lines bigger or smaller depending on the value you specify on your lets say `<p>` or other text element.

[Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)