# How to change br line height inside bootstrap .col

Tags: css

I was looking for changing br size between paragraphs.I found many thing but many of them didn't work.I didn't understand why.In the example below I added 
 tag to seperate my paragraph.But that space is too for me.I tried  but didn't change that spcae height.I don't know how else I can make it more less.On the picture you can see

[image]

Here what I tried below

```
<div class=" container shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded centered" style="margin-top:50px;">

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
                <h4 style="display:inline">Language:</h4>
                <mat-form-field style="margin-left:10px;">
                    <mat-select>
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let lang of languages" [value]="lang.value">
                        {{lang.viewValue}}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
              <h4>Company Size</h4>
              <div>
                Number of Computers:
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input type="number" matInput placeholder="" ngModel name="number" #numCows="ngModel">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div>
                Number of computers necessary
                <br style="line-height:20%">
                needed per year:
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input type="number" matInput placeholder="" ngModel name="number" #numCalves="ngModel">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange;">
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the height of a <br>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br)

Comment: Just use `margin-bottom` instead of `<br>`

Comment: I did   <div style="margin-bottom:25px;"> but didn't work

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek put that inside a div and wrap it in the next line

Comment: @Aravind that would be awesome if you could answer as code

Answer (score 0):

Here it is,

```
Number of computers necessary
       <span style="display:block">
              needed per year:
```

You can increase the space by using `margin-top: 2px;` or what ever number

**[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnkhfp)**

Comment: good solution but when I add a new paragraph under of it,still there's a gap between that paragraph here it is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnkhfp-3vfu9q?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

This would work and be more inline with the code you already have.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 30px">
  Number of computers necessary
</div>
<div>
  needed per year:
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="number" matInput placeholder="" ngModel name="number" #numCalves="ngModel" />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Another option would be to wrap it in a `<p>` and adjust the `line-height`. This option would be better for accessibility since you aren't splitting a sentence up for the purposes of formatting.

```
<p style="line-height: 30px">
  Number of computers necessary
  <br />
  needed per year:
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="number" matInput placeholder="" ngModel name="number" #numCalves="ngModel" />
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the height of an `<br>` element if you really want to like this, for example:

```
<br style="height:30px" />
```

Or like @Suyash said, and what most people would do I think is just add some margin or padding above or below it until it looks how you want it to look.

Comment: Specifying a `height` on a `br` will not change it's height