# How to set the line height of the html.Br tag in Plotly Dash Python?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, plotly

I tried:

```
html.Span(children=[html.Div('Note:'),
                    html.Br(style={'margin-bottom':"2px"})
...
```

I tried also line-height, margin and 2, "2em".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It has probably been solved since, but for me the `line-height` parameter did the trick (though it might depend on the browser):

```py
html.Span(children=[
                html.Div('Note:'),
                html.Br(style={"line-height": "5"})
                ])
```

Also answered more comprehensively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br)